# Language of walks in a grid – context-free?

Tags: context-free, finite-automata, formal-grammars

Consider the infinite two-dimensional grid with integer co-ordinates. A walk in the grid can be represented by a string over the alphabet $\{u,d,l,r\}$, where the letters stand for moving one square up, down, left and right, respectively.

Now consider the langauge of all strings representing closed walks (walks that end at their start point). To me, this would seem like any combination of $u$, $d$, $l$ or $r$. So would the language be represented as $L = \{u,d,l,r\}^*$? If so, this wouldn't be context-free right? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You mean it is not context-free, since you cannot  keep 2 separate counts (one for each direction) with a single stack.

Comment: Grid with integer co-ordinates, do you know what it would be though if the ups and downs or lefts and rights did not need to be the same? So basically representing the functionality of making a path from one point to any other point.

Comment: Each possible string corresponds to exactly one path, and conversely, up to the starting position.

Comment: @babou So would this language be Recursively Enumerable as well?

Comment: @babou Oops. I really must go and learn context-free languages: none of my undergrad courses covered them.

Comment: @learning_user7 It's in LOGSPACE so it's certainly recursively enumerable! Also, note that $\{u,d,l,r\}^*$ is regular so it's certainly context-free. But, as Yuval shows, the actual langauge you're looking for isn't $\{u,d,l,r\}^*$ and isn't context-free.

Comment: To be precise, the strings for closed walks are accepted by "blind counter automata", as studied by Greibach (Remarks on Blind and Partially Blind One-Way Multicounter Machines. Theor. Comput. Sci.  1978): "We consider one-way nondeterministic machines which have counters allowed to hold positive or negative integers and which accept by final state with all counters zero. " Two counters, but a lot more decidability properties if I recall well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your language $L$ were context-free then so would $L \cap u^* l^* d^* r^*$ be. However, $L \cap u^* l^* d^* r^* = \{ u^n l^m d^n r^m : n,m \geq 0 \}$, which is known not to be context-free (this can be proved using the pumping lemma).

Comment: Right that makes sense, but if the language didn't have to go back to where it started, it could just go anywhere(doesn't have to go back where it started), it would still not be context-free, correct? Thanks Yuval Filmus and everyone!

Comment: If it could go anywhere then it's just $(u+l+d+r)^*$, which is regular.

Comment: Paths that go anywhere are regular, as Yuval points out. Paths from $(x,y)$ to $(x',y')$ are strings where $n_r-n_l=x'-x$ and $n_u-n_d=y'-y$, where $n_a$ is the number of $a$'s in the input ($a\in\{u,d,l,r\}$). I assume that's also not context-free, for any fixed choice of the endpoints.

Comment: Yuval, I've clarified the question so you can probably delete your first paragraph.

Comment: Note that Yuval Filmus' proof works because context-free languages are closed under intersection with regular languages (which is not the case with context-free languages).